# How to include the number of days a task has been in a specific status (New, In Progress ...) in a report?

Tags: report, attask

I'm trying to create a report that includes the number of days a task has been in a particular status.  Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this inherently in Workfront. You can build something through the API that runs these calculations there are also partners you can work with to build something.

atappstore also has something they have already built here
http://store.atappstore.com/index.php/product/sla-package/